# UIView TransitionFromView disables scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey there StackOverflow!  I've finished programming my app, and everything is working fine- so I've decided that since the function part is done, I want to start working on form.  However, I have a bit of code that's giving me trouble, and I'm not sure why.  My app has two views that I switch between.  In viewDidLoad, I have these two lines of code:

```
[PlannerView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[PlannerView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 735)];
```

and then later, I switch between the main view and planner view when a button is pressed, like this:

```
    if (isPlannerView) {
//      [self setView:MainView];
    [UIView transitionFromView:PlannerView 
                        toView:MainView
                      duration:0.5 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [self setView:TimerView];
                    }];
    isPlannerView = NO;
} else {
    [UIView transitionFromView:MainView 
                        toView:PlannerView
                      duration:0.5 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    }];
//      [self setView:PlannerView];
    isPlannerView = YES;
}
```

Now, when I use hte commented line of code (self setview), it will scroll with no problems.  However, when I use UIView transitionFromView, it no longer scrolls.  Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for **[transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a)** says:

> This method modifies the views in their view hierarchy only. It does
>   not modify your application’s view controllers in any way. For
>   example, if you use this method to change the root view displayed by a
>   view controller, it is your responsibility to update the view
>   controller appropriately to handle the change.

So make sure that viewDidLoad: is actually being called.  It also states:

> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for
>   the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are
>   disabled for the entire application.) If you want users to be able to
>   interact with the views, include the
>   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction constant in the options
>   parameter.

So make sure that user-interaction is enabled on the view after the animation is finished.

```
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [PlannerView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}];
```

Source: [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Unfortunately, while this sheds some light as to why this may be happening, the suggested code still doesn't work (though it makes no sense to me as to why not). I also tried including UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in the options parameter, but that didn't work either.